# Gitlab: server certificate verification failed

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab, ssl-certificate

I've been granted access to a remote gitlab repo, but I systematically get this error when attempting to `fetch`, `pull` or anything else from it:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.domain.com/project/external/repo.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

So far I have run the following (assembled from various pieces of answers I found online) in an attempt to fix this:

```
openssl genrsa -out gitlab.domain.com.key 2048
openssl req -new -key gitlab.domain.com.key -out gitlab.domain.com.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in gitlabdomain.com.csr -signkey gitlab.domain.com.key -out gitlab.domain.com.crt
sudo cp gitlab.domain.com.key /etc/ssl/private/
sudo cp gitlab.domain.com.key /etc/ssl/certs/
sudo cp gitlab.domain.com.key /etc/gitlab/ssl/ # I had to manually create this directory
sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb # created this file and added the lines "external_url 'https://gitlab.domain.com'" and "nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = yes" to it
sudo cp gitlab.domain.com.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

This did not work. I have also synchronised my system clock with NTC.
I'm running a Linux Mint 19 system, have Git installed and everything is up to date. **I am running a client machine and do not have access to the server.**

What other solutions are there? I can't bypass the security as the project is sensitive.

Comment: It's unclear on which machine (client or server) you are running these commands. If you set up an HTTPS server with a self-signed server certificate, you need to trust that cert on all client machines.

Comment: I am only a client, I'll specify that in the OP

Comment: Then attempting to generate a certificate and trust it locally does nothing. Do you see that any unauthorized user could do the same thing as you? You need to ask the administrator of the server to provide you with the CA or server certificate to trust. It wasn't kind of them to omit this information when providing you access.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I have access to the Gitlab browser UI, can I get a certificate from there?

Comment: As a warning, you should be careful when doing anything with trusting certificates. If you don't know what you're doing you could easily make your entire system insecure.

Comment: How can you trust that the certificate is the real server and not someone impersonating it? Ask the administrator directly.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart considering the changes I've made, should I undo all of them for safety?

Comment: Yes. I would delete the files you created and run `update-ca-certificates` again.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart once I get hold of a certificate, what should I do? I feel like some of the steps I took in my attempt were unnecessary

Comment: Then you should evaluate the security posture of the issuer (is it a CA certificate or just a self-signed server cert?) and then decide if you want to trust it or not (using the last two steps you did). Again, if the administrator of this server  has any idea what they're doing, they should be explaining this to you.